# Why is there a mismatched types error when comparing a value after parsing it from a string?

Tags: rust

I don't understand why I get a type mismatch error when comparing two values after a successful parse. Most of my work has been done using dynamic languages so maybe this is throwing me off. Would this happen in another language such a C++ or C#?

This code is invalid.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input_text = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input_text)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let num_of_books = input_text.trim();
    match num_of_books.parse::<u32>() {
        Ok(i) => {
            if num_of_books > 4 {
                println!("Wow, you read a lot!");
            } else {
                println!("You're not an avid reader!");
            }
        }
        Err(..) => println!("This was not an integer."),
    };
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:31
   |
12 |             if num_of_books > 4 {
   |                               ^ expected &str, found integer
   |
   = note: expected type `&str`
              found type `{integer}`
```

While this code is valid.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input_text = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input_text)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let num_of_books = input_text.trim();
    match num_of_books.parse::<u32>() {
        Ok(i) => {
            if num_of_books > "4" {
                println!("Wow, you read a lot!");
            } else {
                println!("You're not an avid reader!");
            }
        }
        Err(..) => println!("This was not an integer."),
    };
}
```

Comment: You want `if i > 4`.

Comment: Having different types checked at compile time is the *entire purpose* of a statically typed language.

Comment: I agree with SvenMarnach; this is just a typo, and you meant `i` instead of `num_of_books`. I recommend shadowing the variable in this scenario: `match num_of_books.parse::<u32>() {
        Ok(num_of_books) => {`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses. I feel like a fool.

@Shepmaster And I knew that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually due to using the wrong variable in your match branches. This would be a compile-time error in any statically typed language.

When you pattern match on `Ok(i)` you are saying "there is some variable wrapped within an `Ok` -- I am going to call this variable `i` and do something with it inside of this match branch scope."

What you want is:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input_text = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input_text)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let num_of_books = input_text.trim();
    match num_of_books.parse::<u32>() {
        Ok(i) => {
            if i > 4 {
                println!("Wow, you read a lot!");
            } else {
                println!("You're not an avid reader!");
            }
        }
        Err(..) => println!("This was not an integer."),
    };
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=929ca9defbff58e771e8d9131a7d9555)

Comment: "*Rust has pointed out what would be a runtime error in C++ at compile time.*" No. Any statically typed language (including C++) reports the error at compile-time.

Comment: This is true, it has been a while since I used c++.  Such overloaded comparisons are now forbidden with the message: `ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer`

Comment: Note that in C++ you would be using `std::string`, `std::string_view` and the like, not a pointer.

Comment: Marking yours as correct since they other guys didnt write out an answer